# Integrate two requests into one Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, request

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $.ajax({
            url: portfolio_data_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: "id="+$(this).val(),
            success:function(r){
            // succcess call
            }
        })
     }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  value="0" checked>All</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  value="1">AppID</div>  
    <div><input type="checkbox"  value="2">Vendor</div>
</form>
```

I have several checkboxes whose values are passed using a POST request. If one checkbox is selected, the value is passed to the POST request.

But I already have code that passes POST requests:

**list.js**

```
$(function () {   
    var table = $("#portfolio").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": portfolio_data_url,
            "type": "POST"
        },    
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],    
        "stateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "language": datatables_language,    
        "order": [[ $(".portfolio thead th").index($(".portfolio thead .appid")), "desc" ]],    
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": "no-sort"
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

How can I integrate the code into the `list.js` for everything to go with one query.

Because now two different requests are sent which lead to incorrect output of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.DataTable` function to send checkboxes checked value in one request like below:

**Try this:**

```
$(function () {   
    var table = $("#portfolio").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": portfolio_data_url,
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function(d){
                var ids = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                        return this.value; 
                }).get();
                d.ids = ids; 
            }
        },    
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],    
        "stateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "language": datatables_language,    
        "order": [[ $(".portfolio thead th").index($(".portfolio thead .appid")), "desc" ]],    
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": "no-sort"
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

In `Datatable` Using the `data` parameter as a function allows the additional data to send to server

[**Official Documentation**](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

**Note:** You will get checked checkboxes value as an array, You can use `.join(',')` after `.get()` to send values as comma separated string to use directly in query

Also, when user check any checkbox then we can refresh datatable ajax to send updated checked checkboxes like below:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ajax function youy want to re-use is of DataTable's.
It's not a good idea to use the ajax function which is used by some other plugin.

Here the Ajax call you want to Re-Use is used by the function DataTable. Instead of re-using that you can create a wrap-up function which makes ajax request.
Every-time if you want to make ajax request you can call that function with specified parameters.
Example :

```
function customAjax(url,data,method,success_message,fail_message){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:data,
        method:method,
        success:function(response){
            alert(success_message);
        },
        error:function(response){
            alert(fail_message);
        }
    });
}
```

And call using :

```
customAjax("xyx.php","username=abc&password=ushfush","POST","Login Successfull","Something went wrong");
```